# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > Supplied String module notation flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, build.gradle

I am having a a big problem when I am running the app, I got some errors in the gradle version line, I have updated it to the latest one in the build.gradle and in the gradle-wrapper.properties but nothing changed and still have the same error

**app\build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.trux1"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build.gradle-7.2.0-alpha06'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        }
    }
}

// classpath 'com.android.tools.build.gradle-7.2.0-alpha06'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

//implementation
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
 #Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
```

**and this the error**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/mohamed/StudioProjects/trux1/android/app/build.gradle' line: 71

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Supplied String module notation 'com.android.tools.build.gradle-7.2.0-alpha06' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 851ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build.gradle-7.2.0-alpha06'
```

To,

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest), I have replaced it but I got another error  `Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where: Build file '/home/mohamed/StudioProjects/trux1/android/build.gradle' line: 25  * What went wrong:  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
 > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:classpath'.
 > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle-7.2.0-alpha06:.`

Comment: `Required by:  project :app   * Try:   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 1s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`  the rest of the error                              Line 25  `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'`                                                                                Line 71 `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-7.2.0-alpha06'`      @Yashraj

Comment: Update : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0-alpha06'

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace the

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build.gradle-7.2.0-alpha06'
```

To

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build.gradle-7.2.0'
```

and make sure always use the latest version of this Android studio will also recommend you to use the latest version